# Is one letter used in API path a pointer to a particular tech used?

Tags: api, rest

Could someone please help me understand the sacred meaning behind a one letter API paths, like `a` in

```
http://getpocket.com/a/read/327482419
```

and `t` in

```
https://ya.cc/t/fhGASAaasd
```

Is this a pointer to a particular technology being used?

**UPDATE** I do realize that routing/rewriting can be setup to anything, it can be numbers or letters, anything. Is brevity just a matter of choice, like some programmers choose *a* as a variable, while others would choose *apples*?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not such a pointer. There is no reason why it should be. You can configure URL rewriting in all HTTP servers and all application servers.